# Two Javascript Date Variables

Tags: javascript, date

I don't seem to be able to get my head around the syntax required to have two date variables.

```
var videodate = new Date(2014,7,5);
var previousdate = videodate.getDate()-1;
```

This would allow me to have two links on the page:

```
<a href="today.mp4">{videodate}</a>
<a href="yesterday.mp4">{previousdate}</a>
```

What I am finding is that the solutions I've hunted around for use:

```
videodate.setDate(videodate.getDate()-1)
```

but that then changes the 'videodate' variable. I just want to be able to read 'videodate' in order to specify the 'previousdate'!? So something like:

```
var previousdate = new Date(videodate.getDate()-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substract the time in millisecond of a day a build a new date object:

```
var videodate = new Date(2014,7,5);
var previousdate  = new Date(videodate.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

or alternatively use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/), it will make you life easier on date stuff:

```
var videodate = new Date(2014,7,5);
var previousdate = moment(videodate).subtract('days', 1);
```

In both ways the original `videodate` variable will not be touched.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/pcPCJ/

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate new date object for the previous date, setting it to the same date as the first by using `.getTime()`, then do the -1 on it, keeping the two dates independent of one another.

```
var videodate = new Date(2014,7,5);
var previousdate = new Date(videodate.getTime());
previousdate.setDate(previousdate.getDate()-1);
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. Your question was just as correct and replicated the method I used for subtracting the day. However, I am giving the correct one to @irvin-dominin-aka-edward because it will probably be more useful to anyone else that comes by this question. Let me know if there are any potential issues with subtracting milliseconds to get the previous day.

Answer (score 0):

Convert into timestamp

```
var videodatets = new Date('July 07 2014').getTime();

var previousdatets = videodatets-24*60*60*1000;

var videodate=new Date(videodatets);
var previousdate=new Date(previousdatets);
alert(videodate);
alert(previousdate);
```